# AuthenticationHeaderValue:SharedAccessSignature on .NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-authentication

I was authenticating a service with ASP.NET using

```
new AuthenticationHeaderValue("SharedAccessSignature", token);
```

now that my code uses ASP.NET core I don't have that class, so my code uses

```
using (var http = new HttpClient())
{
   using(var request = new HttpRequestMessage(…))
   {
       request.Headers.Add( WHAT)
   } 

}
```

But I don't know how that class was working.

Answer (score 1):

finally intercepted old code with wireshark, seems I have to use:

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"SharedAccessSignature {token}");
```